# wordpress uploading media gets a 403 error when activate a sub-site

Tags: php, wordpress

The situation is I want to integrate a profile filling page with the wordpress multi-site registration procedure. Assume you know the process of blog activation in wordpress multi-site system, when user click the link in the email with the activation key to activate the blog, I hook a profile_setup method to the wpmu_wpmu_activate_blog action, which display a profile filling view. And the profile_setup method do something like below:

```
     class myplugin {
     public function $__construct {
     add_action('wpmu_activate_blog', array( __CLASS__, 'setup_person_signup_profile' ), 20, 3);

     }

    public static function setup_person_signup_profile($blog_id, $user_id, $password) {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['key'])) {
            wp_set_current_user( $user_id);
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
            switch_to_blog($blog_id);

            new profile_person_admin(); //basically do wp_enqueue_media();
            do_action('admin_init');
            echo current_user_can( 'upload_files' ); // print 1
            do_action('load_signup_person_profile',$blog_id); // display profile filling view
            // die();
    }

    }
```

as my code shows, as soon as a new blog and a new user are activated, the profile filling view display to the user, and user need to fill the profile to finally finish registration procedure. and the view show the media upload button successfully, but when clicking the button and upload an image, the upload progress bar reaches end, it meets a http 403 error with fail to load subblogaddress/wp-admin/async-upload.php

I have been dealing with this issue for a while, anybody can help me?